# SSRS print view layout barcode size issue IDAutomationcode39 font

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, bids, ssrs-2008-r2

I have inherited an ssrs report, which prints labels to go on sticker pages. i.e. 10 stickers per page. I have an issue where the barcode (IDAutomation code 39 font) displays incorrectly in print view mode and when printed. When distorted the barcode does not scan. When run in bids it all looks ok print view or not print view.

This image shows the barcode looking OK in normal view mode on the left, then when in print preview or print mode it becomes much smaller. I have coloured the textbox that the barcode is in dark green and the whole area of report section turquoise to show its not a small text box.

[image: screenshot]

This image shows the report looking good in the print preview of bids.

[image: BIDS screenshot]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you've "inherited" the report, I'm assuming it used to work. If so, there must be something different now, in your setup, from the previous, working setup. Can you tell us what's changed and/or what's different from the previous setup?

Comment: I'm not sure what is different from previous setup. The server died, and I was contacted to re install the software. This is the latest version in source control so it's either an environment thing or there was a change not put in source control. I'm hoping to quickly modify the report but so far cannot find out what's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with a server reboot, hope this helps for anyone else who comes here from google.

The reboot is required after installing the font.

Here's a couple of links that led me in the direction of this fix:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/401908/bar-code-does-not-print-in-ssrs

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9b273f37-2160-4014-895a-d20f16c56856/